# Arduino UNO + CNC Shield v3 + Python + 4 stepper motors. Problem = one stepper motor doesn't move

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to make a 4 wheel "car" to move with stepper motors and this is my code:

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>

// Definición de los pines para los controladores de motor
#define motorPin1  2  // X STEP
#define motorPin2  5  // X DIR
#define motorPin3  3  // Y STEP
#define motorPin4  6  // Y DIR
#define motorPin5  4  // Z STEP
#define motorPin6  7  // Z DIR
#define motorPin7  8  // A STEP
#define motorPin8  9  // A DIR

// Creación de instancias de los objetos de motor
AccelStepper motorX1(AccelStepper::DRIVER, motorPin1, motorPin2);
AccelStepper motorY1(AccelStepper::DRIVER, motorPin3, motorPin4);
AccelStepper motorX2(AccelStepper::DRIVER, motorPin5, motorPin6);
AccelStepper motorY2(AccelStepper::DRIVER, motorPin7, motorPin8);

float prevX = 0.0;
float prevY = 0.0;

void setup() {
  // Establecer la velocidad de los motores
  motorX1.setMaxSpeed(300); // Establece una velocidad moderada (puedes ajustar este valor según lo que consideres "suave")
  motorY1.setMaxSpeed(300);
  motorX2.setMaxSpeed(300);
  motorY2.setMaxSpeed(300);
 
  // Establece una aceleración razonable
  motorX1.setAcceleration(600); 
  motorY1.setAcceleration(600);
  motorX2.setAcceleration(600);
  motorY2.setAcceleration(600);

  Serial.begin(9600);
 
}

void moveMotors(long diffX, long diffY) {
  // Configura la distancia que cada motor debe moverse
  motorX1.move(diffX);
  motorY1.move(diffY);
  motorX2.move(-diffX);
  motorY2.move(-diffY);

  // Mueve los motores hasta que alcancen su objetivo
  while (motorX1.distanceToGo() != 0 || motorY1.distanceToGo() != 0 || 
         motorX2.distanceToGo() != 0 || motorY2.distanceToGo() != 0) {
    motorX1.run();
    motorY1.run();
    motorX2.run();
    motorY2.run();
  }

  delay(500); // Espera 0.5 segundos
}

void girar90() {
  motorX1.move(60);
  motorX2.move(60);
  motorY1.move(60);
  motorY2.move(60);

  while (motorX1.distanceToGo() != 0 || motorX2.distanceToGo() != 0 || 
         motorY1.distanceToGo() != 0 || motorY2.distanceToGo() != 0) {
    motorX1.run();
    motorX2.run();
    motorY1.run();
    motorY2.run();
  }

  delay(500); // Puedes ajustar esta pausa según lo necesites
}


void interpretGCode(String code) {
  int xPos = code.indexOf('X');
  int yPos = code.indexOf('Y');
  // ... (otros índices)

  if (xPos != -1 && yPos != -1) { // Verifica si 'X' y 'Y' están presentes
    String xStr = code.substring(xPos + 1, code.indexOf(' ', xPos));
    float xCoord = xStr.toFloat(); // Convierte a float en lugar de int

    String yStr = code.substring(yPos + 1, code.indexOf(' ', yPos));
    float yCoord = yStr.toFloat(); // Convierte a float en lugar de int



    // Calcula las diferencias de coordenadas
    float diffX = xCoord - prevX;
    float diffY = yCoord - prevY;

    //Printa los movimientos
    Serial.print("DIFF:");
    Serial.print(diffX);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.println(diffY);

    // Llama a moveMotors con las diferencias (ajusta la multiplicación si es necesario)
    moveMotors(diffX *10, diffY *10); // Si tu motor necesita valores enteros, necesitarás convertir estos valores.

    // Actualiza las coordenadas previas
    prevX = xCoord;
    prevY = yCoord;
  }
}


void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    String gcode = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    interpretGCode(gcode);
    /*Serial.println("OK");*/
  }
}
```

As you can see it takes some input from interpretgcode and it moves perfectly 3 out of 4 wheels.

Wheels on CNC Shield V2 are -- X,Y,Z and A --

I don't know why the fourth wheel --"A"-- doesn't move.

I replaced the controller chip and I changed the motors and everything works but the A axis.

I think it has to do something with the pins but I'm not sure. Maybe I have to "activate" the fourth axis?

I'm using AccelStepper.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved it, you need to use pin 12 and 13, and put jumpers on the 12-13 pins like in this link: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/arduino-uno-cnc-shield-controlling-4-stepper-motors/913742/2

Comment: It would be nice if you can add some more details to the solution here instead of just including a link, because [links can sometimes stop working](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)